# Geb DSL Modules unrecognized within Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, spock, dsl, geb

[Going off the documentation here](https://gebish.org/manual/1.1.1/#intellij-idea-support) are *Modules* and other Geb DSL not expected to be recognized within a Spock Spec with IntelliJ? This makes using Geb with IntelliJ a bit cumbersome with no DSL reference. [I noticed from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763703/intellij-type-error-when-using-geb-static-content-dsl-with-parameters) that the asker did some custom work to get IntelliJ to wrap and notice the Geb DSL.

My questions is am I doing something wrong or is this expected and has there been any progress on getting the Geb DSL recognized by IntelliJ?

If not does anyone have a workaround for this issue/limitation and or another IDE that does recognized the Geb DSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ has support for Geb DSL, I've been using it for years and [there are even tests in IntelliJ's codebase that confirm it's there](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/groovy/test/org/jetbrains/plugins/groovy/geb/GebTestsTest.groovy).

If you could share how your code looks like and what exactly does not work for you then maybe we can find a problem with your setup or expectations. It would also be good to know whether you are using community edition or professional edition.

Please note that the issue discussed in the question you linked to has been fixed by me in [this PR](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/pull/765) and is no longer present since IntelliJ 2018.2.

**EDIT:**

After reading your comments under my response I now understand what the problem is. Your expectation is that IntelliJ will be able to figure out what the page type at runtime is and provide you with autocompletion. I'm afraid that is simply not possible - you need to track current page instance in your code for IntelliJ to be able to infer types.

Note that tests in [geb-example-gradle](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle) are written in [the very concise, yet dynamic style which means that IntelliJ is not able to infer types](https://gebish.org/manual/current/#dynamism-and-conciseness-vs-tooling-support). What you need to do is to use the [strongly typed style as described in the documentation](https://gebish.org/manual/current/#strong-typing). That section of the docs could do with a bit of improvement because it's not precise - I've created [a Github issue to track that](https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/629).

Essentially, if you tweak [GebishOrgSpec](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/master/src/test/groovy/GebishOrgSpec.groovy) from geb-example-gradle to:

```
class GebishOrgSpec extends GebSpec {

    def "can get to the current Book of Geb"() {
        when:
        def homePage = to GebishOrgHomePage

        and:
        homePage.manualsMenu.open()

        then:
        homePage.manualsMenu.links[0].text().startsWith("current")

        when:
        homePage.manualsMenu.links[0].click()

        then:
        at TheBookOfGebPage
    }
}
```

then IntelliJ will provide you with autocompletion.

Comment: [I actually tried to use the geb-example project here with the issue as described](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle). It would recognize the `at` on the _spock speck_ but if I tried to use anything within `content` from a _Module_  or _Page_ like the `links` on this spec [here](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/75eb30c6cf6b5c7144aeec40dbc29306b1cdfd3b/src/test/groovy/GebishOrgSpec.groovy#L13) then it would be unrecognized by Intellij with no references found. I can't dot chain off the module/page to see its content and etc... is that expected?

Comment: continued... it seems IntelliJ doesn't recognize the references within _Pages_ or _Modules_ on the _Spock Spec_, but the DSL magic should work as expected?

From what I gather I would have to manually initialize a page/module to be able to dot chain and see references for what is within content and or methods on them?

Comment: I've edited my response, hopefully now it answers your question

Comment: This looks like the answer, I missed that in the documentation. Thanks for taking the time to explain and reference the solution!

Comment: You're welcome! Good, valid questions deserve taking time to provide answers. Btw, you can show your appreciation by accepting and/or upvoting my answer. :)